# Malloc behaving strangely when allocating space for ints

Tags: c, visual-studio, malloc, access-violation

Probably I just lack understanding of how malloc works, but I don't see an error with my code:

```
int amount_integers = 2;
int *pointer_to_allocated_memory = (int*)malloc(amount_integers * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < amount_integers; i++)
{
    int *address = &(pointer_to_allocated_memory)[i * sizeof(int)];
    *(address) = 0;
}
```

I'd like to initialize memory for an arbitrary amount of integers (`amount_integers` could be something else than 2). However, the malloc in line 2 seems to misfunction. MSVC's debugger will break at this point (without having defined a breakpoint). When continuing, it will encounter an access writing violation at line 6 (`*(address) = 0;`) when `i` is 1.

What I think I'm accessing:

```
    v pointer_to_allocated_memory[0 * sizeof(int)]
... | sizeof(int) | sizeof(int) | 
                  ^ pointer_to_allocated_memory[1 * sizeof(int)]
```

These should be allocated. Why does the application crash?

Comment: The [] operator already multiplies by `sizeof(int)`. You are indexing beyond the end of the memory and corrupting the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array index is not indexing bytes but array elements, in your case ints:

```
       int *address = &(pointer_to_allocated_memory)[i];
```

valid values for `i` are 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

Because you misunderstand how pointer arithmetic works. It doesn't work with bytes, it works with chunks of memory of `sizeof(T)` bytes, T being the pointer's pointed type. So

```
int *address = &(pointer_to_allocated_memory)[i * sizeof(int)];
```

should be

```
int *address = &ptr[i];
```

instead. (Also note the lack of superfluous parenthesizing and simpler name...)

By the way, [casting malloc is harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).